# Execute python script from PHP with parameters?

Tags: python, web-server, script, php

I cannot figure out, how to pass parameters to PHP `exec` function that I use to run scripts via website.

After some googling I ended up with this:

```
exec("nohup sudo python /home/pi/Python/RGB_Controller/write_color.py ".$HEX." &", $status);

print_r($status);
```

This script simply takes the parameter and writes it into .txt file (if there is parameter). When I run it via bash it works as expected. But when I run it with `exec` the file is not changed.

Running scripts without parameters works fine. This also does not work:

```
exec("nohup sudo python /home/pi/Python/RGB_Controller/write_color.py test &", $status);
```

EDIT: Dammit. So the problem was elsewhere. In my python script that writes the file I had only relative filepath for my file. So it worked probably many times when I tried. Only the data.txt file was being created in the server root directory and thus never updating the one in my Python folder.

Comment: I think you might need to escape the ampersand - you can use `escapeshellcmd()`

Comment: @calcinai but exec without parameters and with ampersand works fine..

Comment: Ah, sorry - I was suggesting that to avoid forking the process, which I now see is intended behavior.

Comment: Just tried it now without nohup and & but nothing changed.

Comment: I know it might be overkill, but have you had a look at something like https://github.com/symfony/process? A library like that would allow much more graceful handling of the process. As a side note, what are you controlling with the python script? I currently maintain a php raspberry pi library and could build it in if it's a common device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like the below code snippet.

```
private function runCom(){
    $command = 'nohup sudo python /home/pi/Python/RGB_Controller/write_color.py' .$HEX.'& > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
    exec($command ,$op);
    $this->pid = (int)$op[0];
}
```

Its like you build your command with necessary arguments as a string.

Then `exec($command ,$op)`. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it as soon as I get home (this Thursday).

Comment: I don't get this :/ It again does not work. When I print the command it looks fine and work locally. I just needed to modify spaces before and after .$HEX. variable in your code. Which of course also didn't help.

Comment: @Filip I will update you by today once I am back home.

Comment: The problem was elsewhere. See my edit.

Comment: @Filip Glad to hear that it worked for you.